# Vuetify Treeview only allow children to be selectable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to only allow children elements in a Treeview to be selectable? A hacky solution I've found is to not set `selectable` on the treeview then add in some checkboxes like

```
<v-treeview
    item-key="id"
    :items="items"
    :search="search"
    :filter="filter"
    :open.sync="open"
    open-on-click
    selection-type="independent"
    selectable
    transition
    v-model="treeVal"
    off-icon="mdi-check-circle-outline"
    on-icon="mdi-check-circle"
  >
  <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
     <v-checkbox
        v-if="!item.children"
        off-icon="mdi-check-circle-outline"
        on-icon="mdi-check-circle"
        dense
     ></v-checkbox>
  </template>
</treeview>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature request open: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11813

For anyone needing it now i made a CSS solution:

```css
.button.v-treeview-node__toggle + button.v-treeview-node__checkbox {
 display: none !important;
}
```

It looks for the collapse toggle button which is only present on root items, and hides the checkbox next to it.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use this solution @Timar Ivo Batis, but it doesn't.

For future needs, I use this CSS code below and it works. Thanks!

`button + button.v-treeview-node__checkbox{ display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <v-treeview :items="data" item-key="id" item-text="name" open-all>
      <template v-slot:prepend="{ item }">
        <v-checkbox v-model="item.selected" v-if="!item.children" />
      </template>
    </v-treeview>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).